# Send token by React

Tags: reactjs, jwt, authorization, token, laravel-sanctum

I wrote this controller's method

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $attr = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($attr)) {
        return $this->error('Credentials not match', 401);
    }

    return response()->json([
       'access_token' => auth()->user()->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken,
       'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

It's return token. But how can I use this token to other requests? So I wrote this code in React
**instance.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
let instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});

export default instance;
```

**Login.js (function handleSubmit)**

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    instance.post('/api/auth/login', {
            email: emailRef.current.value,
            password: passwordRef.current.value
        
    }).then(res => {

        instance.get('/api/me').then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }
        )

    })

}
```

I found information that *withCredentials: true* solve this problem and set cookie in header automatically. But while I try send request to /api/me I have status 401. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your system but after you have been authenticated, on `/api/auth/login`, you don't pass the token to `api/me`.

I think you have to try something like :

```
instance.post('/api/auth/login', {
    email: emailRef.current.value,
    password: passwordRef.current.value

}).then(res => {
    let yourToken  = res.data.access_token; 
    instance.get('/api/me', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'bearer ' + yourToken
        }}).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
})
```

If you need to save and share your token through your application, you can use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Status 401. Problem is that we send token for example `109|VWRqnwlu4n4pA0bOIAcEUTxpM8okqNG3E6hMjjhn` while it should be `bearer |VWRqnwlu4n4pA0bOIAcEUTxpM8okqNG3E6hMjjhn`. Bur problem is bigger. I must save token in order to us in all requests/ I won't login all the time if I want to send request.

Comment: Maybe you should use Context API to save your token. 
See : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html and https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-context-api-and-jwt-to-maintain-user-sessions-eb5602e83a03

Comment: I know, I can use Context, Redux, localStorage, etc but it's not safe. I read that the best way is using http-only cookie but I don't have idea how do that

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to think hiding JWT is secure. You shouldn't hide it. But... you have to VERIFY its signature in your API to protect your system from JWT hijack... http-only with cookie is another way to do that, but I don't know if it's the best way.